# how to improve exception handling in python/django

Tags: python, django, exception

This is an example of my exception handling in a django project:

```
def boxinfo(request, url: str):
    box = get_box(url)
    try:
        box.connect()
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        context = {'error_message': 'Could not connect to your box because the host is unknown.'}
        return render(request, 'box/error.html', context)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        context = {'error_message': 'Could not connect to your box because of an unknown error.'}
        return render(request, 'box/error.html', context)
```

- There is only two excepts now, but it should be more for the several request exceptions. But already the view method is bloated up by this. Is there a way to forward the except handling to a separate error method?
- There is also the problem, that I need here to call the render message for each except, I would like to avoid that.
- And here I also repeat for each except "could not connect to your box because", that should be set once when there appeared any exception.

I can solve it by something like this:

```
try:
    box.connect()
except Exception as e:
    return error_handling(request, e)
```

-

```
def error_handling(request, e):
    if type(e).__name__ == requests.exceptions.ConnectionError.__name__:
        context = {'error_message': 'Could not connect to your box because the host is unknown.'}
    elif type(e).__name__ == requests.exceptions.RequestException.__name__:
        context = {'error_message': 'Could not connect to your box because of an unknown error.'}
    else:
        context = {'error_message': 'There was an unkown error, sorry.'}
    return render(request, 'box/error.html', context)
```

and I could of course improve the error message thing then. But overall, is it a pythonic way to handle exceptions with `if/else`? For example I could not catch `RequestException` here if `ConnectionError` is thrown, so I would need to catch each requests error, that looks more like an ugly fiddling...

Comment: ok this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084360/separating-except-portion-of-a-try-except-into-a-function, there is proposed to handle it in a function with `if type(e).__name__ == 'ReadError'`, is this really the pythonic/django way?

Comment: It's not pythonic. Generally using `__dunder__` methods is a last resort / workaround thing, and checking the class name in particular is very hacky. Try [using `isinstance` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a use case for [decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/309000/2616577). If it's something more general that applies to all views (say, error logging), you can use the [Django exception middleware hook](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/#exception-middleware), but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

With respect to the repetitive error string problem, the Pythonic way to solve it is to have a constant base string with `{replaceable_parts}` inserted, so that later on you can `.format()` them.

With this, say we have the following file `decorators.py`:

```py
import functools

from django.shortcuts import render
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, RequestException


BASE_ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Could not connect to your box because {error_reason}'


def handle_view_exception(func):
    """Decorator for handling exceptions."""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            response = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except RequestException as e:
            error_reason = 'of an unknown error.'
            if isinstance(e, ConnectionError):
                error_reason = 'the host is unknown.'
            context = {
              'error_message': BASE_ERROR_MESSAGE.format(error_reason=error_reason),
            }
            response = render(request, 'box/error.html', context)
        return response

    return wrapper
```

We're using the fact that [ConnectionError is a subclass of RequestException in the requests library](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/exceptions.py). We could also do a dictionary with the exception classes as keys, but the issue here is that *this won't handle exception class inheritance*, which is the kind of omission that generates subtle bugs later on. The `isinstance` function is a more reliable way of doing this check.

If your exception tree keeps growing, you can keep adding `if` statements. In case that starts to get unwieldy, I recommend looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796808/share-python-code-when-handling-multiple-exceptions), but I'd say it's a code smell to have that much branching in error handling.

Then in your views:

```py
from .decorators import handle_view_exception

@handle_view_exception
def boxinfo(request, url: str):
    box = get_box(url)
    box.connect()
    ...
```

That way the error handling logic is completely separate from your views, and best of all, it's reusable.

Comment: This is actually a very good solution. Respects the DRY principle, clearly divides class responsibility throighout. Think it should be accepted.

Comment: Iam not very convinced by this, actually I was looking for a more general solution, so I will also have a look into `process_exception()`, so but I hope I can adjust your solution to my needings. And because it seems that there is no better solutions yet, I will accept it

Comment: @Asara in what way this doesn't cover your use case?

Answer (score 0):

could you have something like this:

views.py

```
EXCEPTION_MAP = {
    ConnectionError: "Could not connect to your box because the host is unknown.", 
    RequestException: "Could not connect to your box because of an unknown error.",
}

UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "Failed due to an unknown error."


def boxinfo(request, url: str):
    box = get_box(url)
    try:
        box.connect()
    except (ConnectionError, RequestException) as e:
        message = EXCEPTION_MAP.get(type(e)) or UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE
        context = {'error_message': message}
        return render(request, 'box/error.html', context)
```

You could then just expand the `EXCEPTION_MAP` and the `except ()` for any other known exception types you're expecting to catch?

if you want to reduce the duplication of `"Could not connect to your box because ...`

You could maybe do:

views.py

```
BASE_ERROR_STRING = "Could not connect to your box because {specific}"

EXCEPTION_MAP = {
    ConnectionError: "the host is unknown.", 
    RequestException: "of an unknown error.",
}
UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "Failed due to an unknown error."

def boxinfo(request, url: str):
    box = get_box(url)
    try:
        box.connect()
    except (ConnectionError, RequestException) as e:
        specific_message = EXCEPTION_MAP.get(type(e))
        if specific_message:
             message = BASE_ERROR_STRING.format(specific=specific_message)
        else:
             message = UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE
        context = {'error_message': message}
        return render(request, 'box/error.html', context)
```

Comment: still, this would make it necessary to put a lot of error handling code into the view method. I my perception, I should immediately leave this method if an exception error happens becausethen there went something wrong and this method is no longer responsible for dealing with it